# Пропускать ошибки php

Tags: php

У меня есть несколько запросов. 
И они могут не выполнятся по вполне нормальным причинам=) По каким - не столь важно.

Вопрос в том как не завершать выполнение скриптов в файле, которые идут после тех запросов в которых может возникнуть ошибка, если появилась ошибка?

Ошибка может возникнуть из-за недоступности одного из серверов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. php.ini:
   display_errors Off
2. vhosts:
   php_flag display_errors Off
3. обернуть в try-catch
4. приглушить ошибки с помощью @

Comment: error_reporting

Answer (score 2):

Кроме вышесказанного от [[@dekameron](/users/13096/dekameron)](/users/13096/dekameron) хочу добавить про обработчик ошибок/исключений. PHP позволяет устанавливать *обработчики* ошибок, которые, в свою очередь, позволяют оформить или проигнорировать ошибку:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile=null, $errline=null, array $errcontext=array())
{
    // внутри реализуется любая логика
    // например, надо останавливаться только на пользовательских ошибках
    if ($errno === E_USER_ERROR) {
       echo 'User error occurred';
       return false; // передать обработку следующему обработчику в стеке
       // в этом случае это будет стандартный обработчик PHP
    }
    return true; // ошибка не будет передаваться дальше и будет считаться обработанной
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
trigger_error('Invisible notice', E_USER_NOTICE); // ничего не выведет
trigger_error('Visible error', E_USER_ERROR); // выведет ошибку и передаст ее обычному обработчику
```

Таким образом, можно просто глушить все ошибки, кроме фатальных
подробнее можно почитать в [доках](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)

Кроме ошибок есть еще незатронутые исключения - исключения в каком-то роде представляют собой продвинутую ошибку, которую можно *ожидать*.

```
try { // пробуем 
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':price', $price);
    $statement->bindValue(':product', $product);
    $statement->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) { // ожидаем исключение типа PDOException
    // Здесь начинает выполняться catch-блок - ура, значит все упало! Грамотно обрабатываем ошибку и завершаем скрипт, ЕСЛИ это необходимо.
    User::sendFlashMessage('Whoops, an error has occured!', User::FLASH_ERROR);
    Logger::log('Couldn\'t update price to {price} for {product}, array('price' => $price, 'product' => $product));
}
```

Чем подход с исключениями лучше и почему я вообще на нем остановился:

- Можно обрабатывать конкретные типы ошибок, оставляя все остальные более высоким уровням. Таким образом можно легко разделить низкоуровневые "база не смогла вставить значения" и "данные выходят за разумные пределы", чтобы в первом случае вывести ошибку базы данных, а во втором - сообщить пользователю о том, что он предоставил неверные данные.
- Обработка ошибок и сами ошибки могут быть разделены несколькими слоями кода, и заботиться о них становится проще
- Исключения, как и любой класс, легко наследуются, что позволяет расщепить любое исключение на несколько дочерних, но ловить их все равно всех вместе:

.

```
class DbConnectionRefusedException extends DbException {}
class DbTransactionFailedException extends DbException {}
class DbInvalidCredentialsException extends DbException {}
```

...

```
try {
    $db = Db::connect();
    $db->insert('supertable', array('data' => 'somedata'));
} catch (DbException $e) { // словит указанное исключение и всех наследников
}
```

- Указанная в вопросе задача с мьютированием решается парой строчек, как в примере выше - достаточно пустого блока `catch (ExceptionClass $e) {}`, чтобы заглушить исключение. Другое дело, что подобные пустые блоки могут вызвать впоследствии некислую головную боль
- Все исключения ловятся "на местах", а на верхнем уровне остается один глобальный обработчик, который выведет красивую страницу 500 и залогирует трейс.
- Не очень относится к PHP, нос помощью try-catch можно задавать поведение приложения и просто ловить на верхнем уровне какой-нибудь ValidationException

**Как это относится к коду с обычноми ошибками вместо исключений?** В PHP (сообществе, не языке самом) принято конвертировать обычные ошибки в исключения `ErrorException` с помощью установки обработчика (который состоит буквально из одной строчки `throw new ErrorException(...);`). Кроме того, ошибки постепенно вытесняются из PHP - медленно, но вы не увидите ни одного современного проекта, который использует ошибки, а не исключения, и "глушилка" (@) стоит обычно только на `session_start()` (и то зря). Рекомендую в части БД сразу перейти на PDO, который будет стрелять PDOException "из коробки".

Информация по обработчику исключений также валяется в [доках](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php), его я не буду расписывать, скажу только, что, в отличие от обычных ошибок исключения ловятся простым `catch`, поэтому предполагается, что попадание исключения в обработчик - это незапланированное событие, после которого скрипт должен будет завершиться.